# How do I reduce opacity of a background color in react native if the rgb value is stored in a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
brandColor = rgb(2,5,2);

pageBackgroundColor :{
    backgroundColor: brandColor,
},
```

I want to add opacity to background color. I know I can either write "rgba(2,5,2,0.5)" or use the inline style in react native. **But I want to use the "brandColor" variable.** I am using this variable in 5-6 different places and don't want to manually update the color every place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your `brandColor` variable a string, you can use string manipulation to add opacity -

```
const brandColor = "rgba(2, 5, 2)";    
function addOpacity(rgbString, opacity) {
  return rgbString.split(')')[0] + "," + opacity + ")"
}
<View backgroundColor={addOpacity(brandColor, 0.5)} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an older question, but maybe somebody is looking for it currently like myself.
I got an error, because rgba with 3 arguments was an invalid format.
My fix:

```js
const brandColor = "rgba(2, 5, 2, 1)";    
function addOpacity(rgbString, opacity) {
  return rgbString.split(', 1)')[0] + "," + opacity + ")"
}
<View backgroundColor={addOpacity(brandColor, 0.5)} />
```

That way we still have functioning base brandColor, and can change the '1' for opacity for other argument :)